Listing system dependencies from a package: "rospack depends" vs "rosdep keys"
I'm on ROS noetic (Ubuntu 20.04) and I'm trying to get a list of dependencies used by our system. For a given package, let's say my_can_pkg which is compiled in my current catkin workspace, the list of dependencies output by rospack depends and rosdep keys (or rosdep install -s) is different.
As an example, here's the output when I run rospack depends my_can_pkg:
catkin
genmsg
genpy
cpp_common
rostime
roscpp_traits
roscpp_serialization
message_runtime
gencpp
geneus
gennodejs
genlisp
message_generation
rosbuild
rosconsole
std_msgs
rosgraph_msgs
xmlrpcpp
roscpp
rosgraph
ros_environment
rospack
roslib
rospy

Here is the output when I run rosdep keys my_can_pkg -i:
python3-yapf-pip
python3-tabulate
python3-autoflake-pip
python3-isort-pip
python3-tqdm
python3-canmatrix
canopen-pip
python-attrs-pip

Why are the 2 sets of dependencies disjointed? Not a single dependency is common between the two lists, why is that?
EDIT: Here are the dependency declarations in the package.xml file
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rospy</depend>
  <depend>canopen-pip</depend>
  <depend>python-attrs-pip</depend>
  <depend>python3-tqdm</depend>
  <depend>python3-tabulate</depend>
  <depend>python3-canmatrix</depend>
  <depend>python3-autoflake-pip</depend>
  <depend>python3-isort-pip</depend>
  <depend>python3-yapf-pip</depend>
```


There are two types of dependencies, there are ROS packages either in your workspace or in an underlay and there system dependencies.
rospack is designed to interact with the ROS packages.
rosdep is designed to interact with the system dependencies.
So the command line tools filter out the other types of dependencies.

This distinction helps!! I was also conflating pre built ROS packages (e g. ros-noetic-rospy) as system dependencies since they're installed via apt, but it appears that the better way of thinking about it is that it's specifically a ros package (e g. a catkin package), so it's shown in the rospack output

Yes, the pre build packages can be best thoughts thought of as an underlay workspace of ROS packages.

I saw this from your ROS discourse cross post ;) .  It's been a while since I ROS1'd but I think the rospack depends is giving you package names and rosdep keys is giving key entries that are in the corresponding rosdep file.  e.g. https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml

@Tully's reply clarified the distinction for me. They're both returning dependencies but rospack is specifically crawling workspaces for ROS/catking workspaces, hence "ROS dependencies" and rosdep gets you non-ROS dependencies, aka "system dependencies"


Why are the 2 sets of dependencies disjointed?

Because the package.xml appears incomplete - it's supposed to also have all the catkin packages (directly) imported by the project.

if that were the case I would expect both lists to contain at least the declared dependencies. However, rospy only shows up in the rospack output, but not rosdep. While the rest of the package.xml dependencies (canopen, yapf, etc) show up in the rosdep output, but not in the rospack output
